# Different ways of writing a sentence for clarity

Tags: difference, sentence-choice

I got the following suggestion from one of the online grammar checker tools.
I wrote:

> In the sum, the nth integer is divided by q.

The correction made shows

> The nth integer is divided by q in the sum.

**Is one clearer than the other? What's the difference between these two ways of

writing sentenced.**
[image]
Also my grammar checker frequently shows this message:
[image]
Is active voice a really better way to write?

Comment: I wouldn't trust those grammar checkers if I were you. If you're checking for typos, such as imaginnation, diferent, or sujestions, it's ok. But for the "rewrite for clarity", hmm...

Answer (score 1):

In this case, both sentences have the same meaning, just with rearranging a few words. I view this change as unnecessary and does not make anything clearer. Both sentences are absolutely fine.